# Select from multiple Tables, Not directly Connected

Tags: sql

I couldn't get best question title to describe my question so forgive if to feel , its not accurate or misleading in anyway.

Table1: UserMaster

```
UserID                                      username
------------------------------------------- ----------
04FF9B2B-465E-4933-95D0-22B139177396        Admin
0DF62BD7-49F9-429E-9046-C5E631B501F3        User
```

Table2 PlanMaster

```
Userid                                     planid
------------------------------------------ ---------
04FF9B2B-465E-4933-95D0-22B139177396       2010
04FF9B2B-465E-4933-95D0-22B139177396       2011
88D68F01-30C8-4C25-B8E2-90CDB5CABC19       2012
```

Table3: PlanSiteMaster

```
planid               siteid
--------            --------
2010                 1
2010                 6
2010                 8
2011                 2
2012                 6
2012                 8
```

Table 4:SiteMaster

```
id          vendorrate
----------- ------------
1           200000
2           250000
3           31500
4           31500
5           45000
6           650000
7           45000
8           585000
9           585000
10          32400
```

Expected Result:

```
Userid PlanId Sum(Vendorrate)
------ ------ ---------------
```

In brief, Usermaster has Number of Users.An User can have multiple plans,stored in PlanMaster.A Plan can have multiple Sites,Stored in PlanSiteMaster. Site details along with their VendorRate are stored in SiteMaster.

What I need, I need List of PlanId along with sum of VendorRate corresponding to each plan for every user.
What I tried:

```
    select a.planid,Amount from
    (select planid,planname,plancreateddate from PlanMaster where status = 1 and userid = @UserId)a,
    (select PlanId, Count(1) as SiteCount from PlanSiteMaster where status=1 group by planid) b,
    (select sum(CAST(vendorrate as Bigint)) as Amount from SiteMaster where id 
in(select siteid from PlanSiteMaster where status=1))c where a.PlanId = b.PlanId and a.PlanId=c.planid;
```

Not able to fetch data from all tables. :(
Every small help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: in Table 4:SiteMaster `id` is `siteId`??

Comment: there is no column like `status`!!

Comment: There are many columns with different names. I just changed it for required ones for easy understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Below query:

```
SELECT U.* FROM 
(SELECT pm.UserID,pm.PlanId, vs.totalVandorRate
 FROM  PlanMaster as pm
JOIN (
     SELECT p.PalnId ,SUM(s.VandorRate) as totalVandorRate 
     FROM PlanSiteMaster as p JOIN SiteMaster as s 
            ON p.SiteId=s.SiteId GROUP BY p.PlanId
    ) as vs
     ON pm.PlanId=vs.PlanId) AS u WHERE u.UserId='88D68F01-30C8-4C25-B8E2-90CDB5CABC19';
```

Comment: It Worked Perfectly. But I am bit worried about performance. As i have just shared sample data but original table has more than 10K+ rows. But Grouping the whole table then selecting matching row than looping over selected values then adding them into a temporary variable Which would be more performance efficient? Anyways, You are not a FrustratedDeveloper but a ExpertDeveloper. :)

Comment: @sanjeev . . . If you have a question about performance, you should probably ask that as a *new* question because this question as already been answered.